# Accessing Shared with Me item using Graph API gives 401 Unauthorized

Tags: office365, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

it's my first time posting a question, sorry if my wording is weird.

My reference is this documentation : https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_sharedwithme
I want to get a list of 'Shared with Me' items of the signed-in user and provide a button containing downloadUrl to download the item of the list. The problem is I can't get the downloadUrl.

What I am doing is :

1. Request `GET /me/drive/sharedWithMe`
This call is a success, the response is generally the same as in the documentation.
Here's a part of the response :

```
object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
      ["@odata.type"]=>
      string(26) "#microsoft.graph.driveItem"
      ["createdDateTime"]=>
      string(20) "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      ["id"]=>
      string(34) "01TWWV5W37UJKHFIUBZZBZDEHOJNVOEZVP"
      ["lastModifiedDateTime"]=>
      string(20) "2016-05-20T05:39:00Z"
      ["remoteItem"]=>
      object(stdClass)#4 (5) {
        ["file"]=>
        object(stdClass)#5 (0) {
        }
        ["id"]=>
        string(34) "01TWWV5W37UJKHFIUBZZBZDEHOJNVOEZVP"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "2NF.PNG"
        ["parentReference"]=>
        object(stdClass)#6 (1) {
          ["driveId"]=>
          string(66) "b!XxxqXZ1tqUGbTG6lCAZp8lCk94i3qvhJt1qf0GJTLQf11toCmqOoS4hkfSFKzG0F"
        }
        ["size"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      ["size"]=>
      int(0)
    }
```

From the response I get the "driveId" and the "id" of the item. They will be used in step 2.
2. Request `GET /drives/<remoteItem.driveId>/items/<id>`
This is how I get the downloadUrl, but this call gives me this 401 Unauthorized error response :

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.","innerError":{"request-id":"64f90e20-92a4-4002-8833-da5de026c076","date":"2016-05-27T10:30:58"}}}
```

To fix this, I have attempted to enable some permissions : Files.Read.All & Sites.Read.All .
Here is a part of my decoded access_token to see all of my enabled permissions

```
scp: "Calendars.ReadWrite Contacts.ReadWrite Directory.ReadWrite.All Files.Read Files.Read.All Files.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All Mail.ReadWrite Mail.Send Sites.Read.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadWrite",
```

What I am asked here is : why it gives me 401 Unauthorized error? and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance, and sorry for that long horizontal code part and bad english.

Comment: For your scenario you should be able to use GET /drive/items/01TWWV5W37UJKHFIUBZZBZDEHOJNVOEZVP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked in github of microsoft graph api and found my answer there. 
Here's the [link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/299)
What causing the 401 Unauthorized error is my user account don't have access to http://mytenant.sharepoint.com/ .
Now that the permission is given, and I request step 2 again. The response is containing the downloadUrl which I need.
Thanks for the answer, and sorry if I take a bit of your time.

Answer (score 0):

When looking up items via the sharedWithMe to reference the item you should use the id on the returned item, not the remote item reference information.

The item returned by sharedWithMe is a special tunnel within the OneDrive to actual item whose information is provided in the remoteItem facet.

For better readability here is an example json for an item returned by SharedWithMe:

```
{
    "id": "DA5D51067000136E!303",
    "remoteItem": {
        "id": "8BF6000DBC6C4A4C!3275",
        "parentReference": {
            "driveId": "8bf6000dbc6c4a4c"
        }
    }
}
```

To retrieve the contents of the item information, use the following GET request on the default drive

```
GET /drive/items/DA5D51067000136E!303
```

Comment: I try your suggestion, but unfortunately, it's still not working(same 401 error). I wonder why my id of my item and the id of the remoteItem facet both are the same value, not different like yours.